# Restarting gdm in 18.04 doesn't work

Tags: xorg, 18.04, gdm

When I try to run one of these commands:

```
sudo service gdm restart
sudo service gdm3 restart
```

the system gets stuck in a loop. It goes from the graphical interface to a black screen, then a terminal-like screen with lots of `[ OK ]` and then again GUI, this repeats cca every second.

It is impossible to stop this, as GUI ceases to respond to any keystrokes and `tty` randomly misses some of them (so that it's not possible to correctly input the password).

What is the correct procedure for restarting X then?
(I'm on a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Acer A315)

Comment: I think the new command is `sudo systemctl restart gdm.service` as Ubuntu can be using systemd

Comment: @SmitTheLastFirefoxUser That does the same thing for me...

Comment: I don't why but this should work if Ubuntu is using systemd as this works for me in arch Linux with systemd. Look like Ubuntu does something else behind the scenes that I am yet to find.

Comment: This was an issue too in Solus Linux - This was solved there after update of gdm and after update of NVIDIA drivers with update of gnome - this issue is caused by a bug in NVIDIA.

Answer (score 7):

gdm may be buggy.

As a workaround, I use lightdm.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Choose lightdm as the display manager. And X restart works.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: I must agree with you. It's quite rare to reproduce the same behavior two or more times, even in a good scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Go Ctrl-Alt-F6 to get a tty;

then follow @Vajira Prabuddhaka at: [GDM3 does not start in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050672/gdm3-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-18-04)

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

next:

```
sudo gnome-shell gnome
```

then:

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```