# GDM stopped starting when booting Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10, gdm

It's been addressed here
[GDM3 does not start in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050672/gdm3-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-18-04) but none of the solutions proposed worked for me (and the topic is about 18.04).

I have disabled wayland as proposed, but did not solve the problem.

If i connect thru SSH and `sudo systemctl start gdm` it will work and start gdm. But if i boot the system, it just gives a blank (black) screen.

`sudo systemctl enable gdm` does not work. It gives a comprehensive message that it's not the correct way to enable this service.

How can I re-enable gdm?

Have also tried to uninstall and then install it again (the gdm package) - did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command to choose a login manager:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

You should be able to select `gdm3`.