# Why is my ubuntu virtual machine freezing right before sign up?

Tags: 16.04, vmware, 19.04, vmware-player

I have a virtual machine in VMware12 I recently upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 to the latest Ubuntu LTS version. But it's freezing in startup.

[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACyxu.png), I have really important work in this virtual machine, that I need to continue working on.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Please can you reconcile the title and your contents?

Comment: Thanks  @GeorgeUdosen, I edited the title.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050672/gdm3-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-18-04/1079363#1079363)

modifying `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` uncommenting or enabling `WaylandEnable=false`