# Boot hangs at /dev/sda6 clean XXXX/XXXC files, YYYY/YYYY blocks followed by a blinking cursor

Tags: boot, 18.04

I installed Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 on a VM environment on the cloud. I set up ssh and it works perfectly - I can ssh to the VM using putty. However, when I boot up the machine to access the GUI, it hangs as shown on the image.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050672/gdm3-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: define "upgrade" generally this term refers to changing out the hardware inside the computer but I guess you meant "update"?

Comment: Thanks for the correction mate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GDM3 does not start in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050672/gdm3-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @tatsu Well, what does `apt-get upgrade` do then? @alexander Please specify what you updated/upgraded. I also cannot understand your mentions of SSH and VM. From which machine do you SSH to which? What is running in the VM and what is the host? What does the screenshot refer to?

Comment: @Melebius VM meaning Virtual machine. I'm SSH from my machine to my Virtual Machine. Ubuntu is running in the VM and the host is windows 10. All this is after I did sudo apt-get update. The screenshot refers to where I'm stuck when trying to access the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Does this mean you can still use SSH? Can you use a [virtual console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-console-and-gui)? Have you tried any advice from the page that frk and I linked? Please [edit] your question to include all the information. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage.