# cannot start TightVNC Server as a systemd service on Ubuntu 19.10 (google compute engine)

Tags: gnome, vnc

I am able to run without using systemd.

The config looks like so:

```
ubuntu@yocto:~/.vnc$ cat xstartup
#!/bin/sh

# [ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic &
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session &
```

I start it like so:

```
ubuntu@yocto:~$ vncserver -geometry 1920x1200 -depth 24

New 'yocto.c.annotator-1286.internal:1 (ubuntu)' desktop at :1 on machine yocto.c.annotator-1286.internal

Starting applications specified in /home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/ubuntu/.vnc/yocto.c.annotator-1286.internal:1.log

Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /home/ubuntu/.vnc/passwd :1 to connect to the VNC server.
```

it runs correctly like so:

```
ubuntu@yocto:~$ vncserver -list

TigerVNC server sessions:

X DISPLAY # RFB PORT #  PROCESS ID
:1      5901        1624
ubuntu@yocto:~$
```

I create an ssh tunnel on macOS like so:

```
gcloud compute --project "annotator-1286" ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "ubuntu@yocto" -- -NL 5901:localhost:5901
```

and then I can connect with the "Screen Sharing.app" by pointing to localhost:5901.

[image]

However, if, instead of manually staring the service, I try to run it as a systemd service, following [these instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/530598/72482):

```
ubuntu@yocto:~$ cat .local/share/systemd/user/vncserver@.service
[Unit]
Description=TigerVNC Service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver :%i -localhost no
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Enabling and starting:

```
ubuntu@yocto:~$ systemctl daemon-reload --user
ubuntu@yocto:~$ systemctl enable vncserver@1 --user
Created symlink /home/ubuntu/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/vncserver@1.service → /home/ubuntu/.local/share/systemd/user/vncserver@.service.

ubuntu@yocto:~$ systemctl start vncserver@1 --user
```

It seems to actually start vnc server:

```
ubuntu@yocto:~$ vncserver -list

TigerVNC server sessions:

X DISPLAY # RFB PORT #  PROCESS ID
:1      5901        1287
ubuntu@yocto:~$
```

But if you try connecting to this, the screen will be blank due the following errors:

```
ubuntu@yocto:~$ systemctl status vncserver@1 --user
● vncserver@1.service - TigerVNC Service
   Loaded: loaded (/home/ubuntu/.local/share/systemd/user/vncserver@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-04-16 02:00:21 UTC; 3s ago
  Process: 3493 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1 > /dev/null 2>&1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3499 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver :1 -localhost no (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/vncserver.slice/vncserver@1.service
           ├─3507 /usr/bin/Xtigervnc :1 -desktop yocto.c.annotator-1286.internal:1 (ubuntu) -auth /home/ubuntu/.Xauthority -geometry 1900x1200 -depth 24 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbau
           ├─3511 vncconfig -iconic
           ├─3515 dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session
           ├─3516 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
           ├─3521 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
           ├─3526 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
           ├─3530 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
           ├─3535 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o big_writes
           ├─3545 /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver --no-daemon
           ├─3551 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
           └─3561 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=secrets

Apr 16 02:00:22 yocto gnome-session[3512]: gnome-session-binary[3512]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Apr 16 02:00:22 yocto gnome-session-binary[3512]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Apr 16 02:00:22 yocto org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3572]: Window manager warning: Unsupported session type
Apr 16 02:00:22 yocto gnome-session[3512]: gnome-session-binary[3512]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Apr 16 02:00:22 yocto gnome-session-binary[3512]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Apr 16 02:00:22 yocto gnome-session[3512]: gnome-session-binary[3512]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Apr 16 02:00:22 yocto gnome-session-binary[3512]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Apr 16 02:00:22 yocto gnome-session-binary[3512]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Apr 16 02:00:22 yocto gnome-session[3512]: gnome-session-binary[3512]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Apr 16 02:00:22 yocto gnome-session-binary[3512]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
ubuntu@yocto:~$
```

These gnome errors are quite generic and I'm having difficulty debugging this problem.
I don't quite understand why I only get these errors when running as a systemd service.

I did have to disable Wayland like so:

```
ubuntu@yocto:/etc/gdm3$ cat custom.conf
# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin = user1
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true
```

as a [work-around](https://askubuntu.com/a/1079363/458965) for this:

```
ubuntu@yocto:~/.vnc$ systemctl status gdm
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-04-15 23:17:56 UTC; 26min ago
 Main PID: 1125 (gdm3)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4410)
   Memory: 4.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
           └─1125 /usr/sbin/gdm3

Apr 15 23:17:44 yocto systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
Apr 15 23:17:56 yocto systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Apr 15 23:17:56 yocto gdm-launch-environment][1130]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Apr 15 23:19:31 yocto gdm3[1125]: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Apr 15 23:19:31 yocto gdm3[1125]: Child process -1149 was already dead.
Apr 15 23:19:31 yocto gdm3[1125]: Child process -1149 was already dead.
Apr 15 23:19:31 yocto gdm-launch-environment][1917]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Apr 15 23:19:32 yocto gdm-launch-environment][1917]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Apr 15 23:19:32 yocto gdm3[1125]: Child process -1944 was already dead.
```