# Black logon screen after change of background screen with focalgdm3

Tags: 20.04

I've done everything like in the instruction on the focalgdm3 github: https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/focalgdm3. My Ubuntu version is 20.04 and it's fresh install like recommended in the Readme.md. After script execution and reboot I have black screen, when I want to login there's need to open terminal (alt + F1). I also tried to use reset parameter `./focalgdm3 --reset`, but not helped.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem and it's here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1197587/1174983. I hope it will help someone.