# "Topaz is not supported in kfd" after upgrade to 21.04

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, 21.04, amdgpu

After upgrading to 21.04 my notebook freezes in login screen. If I start without gdm, the message I see in console is "Topaz is not supported in kfd"
It works fine with 'nomodeset' in grub.
My graphics card is:
Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile]

Is it a misconfiguration or wrong driver installed?

Thanks in advance.

*edit* some more info:

```
    walter@NoteWIM:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] senha para walter: 
  *-display DISPONÍVEL      
       descrição: VGA compatible controller
       produto: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       ID físico: 2
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:02.0
       versão: 0b
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuração: latency=0
       recursos: memória:b0400000-b07fffff memória:c0000000-cfffffff porta de E/S:5000(tamanho=64) memória:c0000-dffff
  *-display DISPONÍVEL
       descrição: Display controller
       produto: Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile]
       fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:03:00.0
       versão: 00
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
       configuração: latency=0
       recursos: memória:a0000000-afffffff memória:b0000000-b01fffff porta de E/S:3000(tamanho=256) memória:b0900000-b093ffff memória:b0940000-b095ffff
```

Comment: How can any one know, you never said what driver is installed.

Comment: I have the same warning with a Radeon M445, it’s just a warning, nothing more; it’s probably unrelated, because my GDM works fine… in Wayland and Xorg.

Comment: Presumably, your laptop has an integrated GPU also? I have Intel HD Graphics. It’s possible the fault lies there instead. Is your BIOS up to date?

Comment: I added the output of "lshw -c video" and will look for a BIOS update.

Comment: Does this answer resolve your issue? https://askubuntu.com/a/1079363/287379

Comment: You can disable the GUI so you can edit this file as suggested by adding the `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` to your kernel parameters. If you are stuck with this, you can go to chat.

Comment: updated the bios and it is working fine! shame on me :-( Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the notebook bios and everything is working fine.